# MongoDB - show all files in a db

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to insert a uploaded text file into database using pymongo and then display it on the webapp. I am trying to show if the files are inserted in the database (MongoDB). How can i check if a file has be inserted in MongoDB shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Mongo shell you could first switch to the database you've just imported:

```
use db_name
```

If you don't know the database name, check the existing databases:

```
show dbs
```

Then query the collection for the documents:

```
db.coll1.find()
```

where coll1 is the collection name.

If you don't know the collection name, check the existing collections:

```
show collections
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used [insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) method and you want to immediately check completed successfully, you can check method's [result](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#writeresult).